# Бот не отвечает на команды

Tags: python, бот, discord

Когда я пишу команду например -balance он не отвечает. А send_message_every_3_days он отлично работает.

````
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
import asyncio
import random

TOKEN = ''  # Replace with your token
YOUR_CHANNEL_ID =   # Replace with your channel ID

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents=intents)

balances = {}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Bot successfully logged in as {bot.user.name}')
    await send_message()
    send_message_every_3_days.start()

@tasks.loop(hours=72)
async def send_message_every_3_days():
    await send_message()

async def send_message():
    channel = bot.get_channel(YOUR_CHANNEL_ID)

    if channel:
        a = random.randint(1, 500)
        await channel.send(f"Today's ChessCoin exchange rate is: {a}")
    else:
        print("Failed to find the specified channel.")

@bot.command()
async def balance(ctx):
    user_id = ctx.author.id
    if user_id not in balances:
        balances[user_id] = 100
    balance_amount = balances[user_id]
    await ctx.send(f"Your balance is: {balance_amount}")

@bot.command()
async def buy(ctx, amount: int):
    user_id = ctx.author.id
    if user_id not in balances:
        balances[user_id] = 100
    balance_amount = balances[user_id]
    if amount > balance_amount:
        await ctx.send("Insufficient balance.")
    else:
        balances[user_id] -= amount
        await ctx.send(f"You have successfully bought {amount} ChessCoins.")

@bot.command()
async def sell(ctx, amount: int):
    user_id = ctx.author.id
    if user_id not in balances:
        balances[user_id] = 100
    balance_amount = balances[user_id]
    balances[user_id] += amount
    await ctx.send(f"You have successfully sold {amount} ChessCoins.")

bot.run(TOKEN)
================ RESTART: C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/chessbot1.3.py ================
[2023-07-02 15:33:12] [WARNING ] discord.ext.commands.bot: Privileged message content intent is missing, commands may not work as expected.
[2023-07-02 15:33:12] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
[2023-07-02 15:33:14] [INFO    ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: 735df2d3b988285bf74841c7c512e863).
Bot successfully logged in as ChessBot```
````

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно это из-за интентов, замените в коде

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
```

на:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
```

И уберите эти две строчки:

```
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False
```

Также включите интенты в discord developer portal , если ещё нет:
[image: intents]